# Unsure of correct type and using 'any' causes compile error due to type-safety

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this in my `Landing.tsx`:

```
<Pless handleClose={this.hidePless} showPless={this.state.showPlessPrompt} />

hidePless = () => {
this.setState({ showPlessPrompt: false });
};
```

In my `Pless.tsx` I have:

```
interface Props {
    handleClose: any;
    showPless: boolean;
}

export class Pless extends React.Component<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I run my application I get this:

> Failed to compile.
> C:/Users/.../Paperless.tsx
> (6,18): Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.

Most likely a silly question but what should the type be?

Comment: Since `hidePless` doesn't take any arguments and doesn't return anything, you can just type it as `handleClose: () => void;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a void function as you are not returning anything from it, just doing something inside of it.

```
interface Props {
    handleClose: () => void;
    showPless: boolean;
}
```

Should keep the typescript compiler happy.